# How to setup Shipping zones based on custom country list in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I changed the list of shipping countries to my own:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries', 'set_country_list' );
function set_country_list() //changed the method to simplify
{
        $countriesDS = mylist.txt(); //[IT] => 'Italy' as example
        foreach ($countriesDS->rows as $countryDS) {
            $countries[$countryDS->iso_code] = $countryDS->name;
        }
    }
    return $countries;
}
```

So, now when I'm trying to set up different shipping zones some of my countries are missing and some of extra.

Question: how can I put in Shipping zone dropdown list only countries from my list?

Answer (score 0):

It was much easier than I thought:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_continents', 'set_continents_list' );
function set_continents_list()
{
    $continents = [
        'R1' => [
            'name' => 'USA/Canada',
            'countries' => [
                'US',
                'CA',
                //your codes of countries
            ]
        ],
        // ...
    ]
    return $continents;
}
```

It's not really grouping by continents but I guess there is nothing to worry